# What does "ending one minute at a time" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Fight Club (1999)*, Narrator facing insomnia:

> Narrator: You wake up at SeaTac. SFO. LAX. You wake up at O'Hare.
> Dallas Fort Worth. BWI. Pacific. Mountain. Central. Lose an hour. Gain
> an hour. This is your life, and it's **ending one minute at a time**.

What does "ending one minute at a time" mean?

Comment: Have you considered watching the movies you're watching with subtitles in your native language? It could help you narrow down why you don't understand some of the phrases, follow the plot better, or even solve some of your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "your life is ending", it means you're dying. In this context it's used somewhat metaphorically as a reminder of mortality - you might not be terminally ill or in a situation where you'll soon die, but nevertheless you're still getting closer to death every minute.